# How to install package import_ipynb with anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, installation

I take jupyter notebook with this line in the import :

```
import import_ipynb
```

When I run the notebook iI got the error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import_ipynb'

I try to install with anaconda :

`conda install import_ipynb`
or 
`conda install import-ipynb`

But it dont find the package, but with pip I got no problem :

`pip install import_ipynb`

Any idea with anaconda ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you activated your env before calling `pip install`? Otherwise, you might have just installed into a system Python.

Comment: Hello merv, yes I activate my env, wiich command work for you ? conda install import_ipynb or conda install import-ipynb ? Thx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that "package" - really, it's just a script - doesn't properly list it's dependencies in `setup.py`. I also can install it from `pip`, but it shows it can't load because it references `nbformat`. Using

```
conda install nbformat
```

get's it working for me.

---

#### Recommendation

I don't know this package space, but it seems like [**nbimport**](https://github.com/deathbeds/importnb) is a far more mature solution for such functionality. It is available on Conda Forge (`conda install -c conda-forge nbimport`) and appears to be quite popular (> 20K downloads).